# Printing multiple instances of a number or a character by using format specifiers

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Is it possible to for example print more than 1 number using format specifiers?

```
printf("%05d",5);
```

This will print 00005

Is there a way to make it print ----5 for example using these format specifiers?

Comment: Do you want to print more than one number, or one number plus some dashes?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use alloca then a not so elegant solution would be:

```
printf("%s%d", (char*)memset(memset(alloca(4), '\0', 4), '-', 3),5);
```

If you can allow c++, then you can try this which looks little more elegant:

```
printf("%s%d",std::string(3,'-').c_str(),5);
```

Both these cases will give out `---5`

Comment: So your answer is "no"

Comment: Not really, `alloca` is bundled in most of the standard GCC versions so "yes" is what I believe my answer is

Comment: You don't need `alloca` for this, calling `alloca` with a constant size makes no sense at all. A simple compount literal `(char[5]){ 0 }` would suffice.

Comment: The question is about using printf's format specifiers for this, not constructing the string by hand.

Comment: @Neowizard Ah, then you're right. In that case, I don't know if it can be done with just format specifiers. I'll take my answer down if this alternative isn't what OP wants. Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want. I think the closest is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// FILLER_DASH needs to be long enough for all use cases
const char *FILLER_DASH = "---------------------------------------------------";

int main(void) {

    const int field_width = 10;

    for (int number = 1 ; number < 1100000; number += (number + 90)) {
        // zero or negative numbers not supported by this simple formula
        int digits = log10(number) + 1;
        printf("%.*s%d\n", field_width - digits, FILLER_DASH, number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It uses the `*` in format specifier to take field width from arguments, and then uses a string to provide characters to be printed.

It uses base 10 logarithm to get number of base-10 digits in a number, which involves implicit conversions from `int` to `double` for logarithm function and then back to `int` for `printf` format. This logarithm is only defined for positive numbers (so in this case integers 1 and greater), if you want 0 or negative number support then they need to be handled as special cases (basically 3 branch if-elseif-else ladder).